# How do our eyes see an inverted image?

Tags: brain, vision, eyes, neurology, perception

How exactly do our eyes see an inverted image of what we are looking at? 
Does it have something to do with the shape of our lens (i.e. convex)?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Inverted image on the retina.]

This isn't particular to eyes. Anything without mirrors would show the same behavior.